# Getting product price in application level defined currency

Tags: intershop

I am following this [example](https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/2U8241#Cookbook-Pricing-Recipe:ObtainaProduct'sPrice), and as shown I want to get price of product on ISML using following piece of code (`ProductBOPricingExtensionImpl` contains method that accepts only price type and currency):

```
ProductBO:Extension("Pricing"):Price("SalePrice",{currency_here})
```

Problem is, I don't know how to acquire any currency object to put in there, and the best way it would be to somehow get default/fallback currency defined on application level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print out the price using this module. Also shows how you get the currency

```
<isinclude template="modules/Modules">
...
<ISProductPrice 
            ProductBO="#ProductBO#"
            Currency="#CurrentRequest:Currency#"
            ShowInformationalPrice="true"
        >
```

checkout the documentation in `app_sf_responsive/staticfiles/cartridge/templates/default/modules/product/Modules.isml`

It takes different scenarios into account, like if the customer is login and is eligible for a discount.